# Do \fboxs float, or do they stay right where you put them?

Tags: floats, fbox

Do `\fbox`s float, or do they stay right where you put them? Also, will LaTeX ever insert a page break midway through an `\fbox`?

Comment: They do float if there are used in a floating environment like `figure`, as all its content floats then, but they don't float on there own.

Comment: are you sure that this is a good way to learn latex? You are asking very many questions but not taking any heed of the comments asking you to edit/clarify any of your existing ones and not accepting any answers

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Each question should be evaluated on its own merit, as if they were asked by different users. The fact that some of my other questions were unclear is not relevant to this question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The primary benefit of stack-overflow is **not** for the question asker to learn the answer to their question. It does not matter if I learn `LaTeX` or not. It does not matter if asking questions is a good way for me to learn or not. The primary benefit goes not to me, but to people using google to search for the same topic. The question asker suffers the cost of typing up the question and waiting for an answer so that a 100 people using google to search for the same thing, do not have to. I assure you that other people also want to know if `framed boxes` "float" or not.

Comment: I didn't comment on the question, I just commented pm your actions and whether asking this many questions is useful. Actually this question is perhaps a good example of the things discussed there it probably would not help to have a MWE and is quite clear as it is, so it wouldn't help to have an "automatic" "please add a MWE comment.

Comment: @IdleCustard as a general rule I agree with you see my comments [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7998/when-does-it-make-sense-to-post-an-additional-answer/8001#8001) that the OP getting an answer isn't the most important thing.  But as a social activity just posting lots of very basic questions without stopping to consider any of the answers that people provide does discourage people to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\fbox`es don't float because they're not set up as a float. Also, since they're set as an unbreakable block, they will never break across the page boundary. There are options to have a framed box break across the page boundary (like that supplied by [`mdframed`](//ctan.org/pkg/mdframed)).