# For Italicization, which command in LaTeX has turn-on behavior only?

Tags: italic, emphasis

### Toggle, Turn-on, and Turn-off

There are three types of behavior:

1. **TOGGLE** Behavior

   - if italics were ON, turn italics OFF
   - if italics were OFF turn italics ON
2. **TURN ON** Behavior

   - If already on, stays on.
   - if italic text mode is turned on, keep it on
   - if italic text mode was turned off, turn italics on
3. **TURN OFF** Behavior

   - If already off, stays off.
   - if italic text mode is turned on, turn it off
   - if italic text mode was turned off, keep it off

### Example of a Toggle Italics Command

`\em` has toggle behavior. Which letter `A`s in the following source code snippet become italic in the output depends completely upon whether the first line is commented out or not.

```
% \em
AAA \em AAA \em AAA
```

We could get:

> AAA *AAA* AAA

or

> *AAA* AAA *AAA*

### Question:

### For Italicization, which command in LaTeX has ***turn-on*** behavior only?

Comment: `\itshape` (also `\em` is a deprecated command in LaTeX.)  See [Will two-letter font style commands (\bf , \it , …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361)

Comment: @AlanMunn Actually, I think that `\em` is an exception to the two-letter-deprecation rule. `\emph` is defined with `\DeclareTextFontCommand{\emph}{\em}` as `\textit` is defined with `\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textit}{\itshape}`...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik : I think you are missing some inner braces in your definition.

Comment: @HerbSchulz Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. The commands I mentioned I copied from `latex.ltx` (lines 4056 and 4060).

Comment: As a general rule of toggles and on-off switches, it is *my understanding* that (La)TeX only really uses "Turn On" behavior (as OP words it).  For example, to "turn off" italics, you don't actually turn off italics...instead you turn on upright/normal (i.e. `\upshape` or `\textup{...}`).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik:Sorry, it appears that the `\DeclareTextFontCommand` command supplies the necessary braces to isolate the declaration's effect. Otherwise the it would be an unending change.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Technically that's true.  It's really not recommended to use `\em` in LaTeX user documents I think.  `\emph` has particular properties (such as alternating) when nested, and is not equivalent to `\textit` hence the different internal definitions.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469484/do-fboxs-float-or-do-they-stay-right-where-you-put-them#comment1181973_469484

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

Your idea that `\em` is a toggle is wrong. Its standard implementation is to change the shape from upright to italics or conversely, but it is not *designed* to perform that action. It can do *anything*, if the document class modifies its implementation. It is a generic command for emphasis, not for switching to italics; it happens that the common way to emphasize text is printing it in italics (or in upright if the current font is slanted).

So you should *not* rely on `\em` switching from upright to italics or conversely.

A correct definition of `\em` should be

```
\@nomath\em
<test>
  \eminnershape
\else
  <default action>
\fi
```

The standard `<test>` is `\ifdim\fontdimen1\font>0pt`, which returns true if the current font is slanted. The standard `<default action>` is `\itshape`.

The standard definition of `\eminnershape` is `\upshape`.

Comment: Alright, `\em` might not toggle between italics and non-italics, but it does toggle. I realize that you might defined "emphasized" text to be boldface instead of italic. In that case, `\em` toggles between boldface and non-boldface. Whether it be boldface, or italics, or something else, the behavior of using `\em` is completely dependent on whether `\em` was used an even or odd number of times in the earlier part of the document. If "emphasized" mode was turned on, `\em` it turns off. If it was off, it turns on. The question still remains, how do you get a turn-on-only version of `\em`?

Comment: @IdleCustard I continue to disagree. The *standard* implementation of `\em` seems to be like a toggle, but you should not rely on this as document classes are allowed to do whatever they prefer with `\em`.

Comment: Okay, my description of `\em` is wrong if someone implements `\em` in some strange way. There is a still a question, which command in LaTeX has turn-on behavior only for italics?